# How can I contribute to others with examples

Tags: discussion

Sometimes after a couple of minutes, sometimes hours, or days, I realized a nice drawing (most of them for math, sometimes physics). But I want to share (give things back to the forum) my work (and the work of others). 
Is there a place where this can be done. Not like a question, but just giving the code and a screenshot of an example.

Comment: You could contribute them to the [TeX Examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/).

Comment: http://www.texample.net/ is a nice place.

Comment: Open up a blog and post them as much as you can.

Comment: as already commented, [texample.net](http://www.texample.net) is a nice place.  but do yourself (and others) a favor ... enlist the good will of someone whose expertise you trust and ask them to review your code for clarity and the absence of questionable or obsolete techniques.  your skill will grow, and with good examples in front of the public, you will become recognized as a "trusted advisor".

Comment: @barbarabeeton I will remember this when am quoting you :)

Comment: sorry, I looked very carefully, before posting, but couldn't find it. May be because I'm not a native speaker, my English search items were not good enough...

Comment: Or maybe because it was in meta? ;)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The problem is that I don't know much people around me using LaTeX. Exactly 2 persons... Here I know some people and therefore was my question...   To percusse: I don't have a site or blog, so if I should start, it would just be a little little little dot on the internet.

Comment: @Clément yes it was there, and I don't understand the difference between the two. (Like I said, I'm not native speaker...)

Comment: @Arne -- you don't have to ask someone in the next office.  if you respect someone whose answers appear in this forum, ask politely in chat if they'd review something for you.  i've met some marvelous people through tex mailing lists and forums, and as has been observed here more than once, the members of this community are actually friendly!

Comment: I totaly agree about the friendliness of this forum. I will follow your advice and try chatting about my examples before posting. Am I correct, because I couldn't find it, that there is no direct chat possibility in this forum?

Comment: @Arne -- if you click on the "stackexchange" text in the upper-left-hand corner of the window in which you are reading this, you will see a number of options, including "chat".  by clicking on that, you should get a new window with a number of chat rooms laid out.  since you are coming from a tex-related chat room, the most prominent rooms shown should also be tex-related.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I didn't know that. I always use the link at the bottom of the page....

Answer (score 2):

you may first try to think why your specific example of code/graphic is important to be shared with others. I am sure there are plenty of such cases since I spend daily some hours on reading code of other people to learn new things. simple because a graphic looks nice is not enough and will cause spamming but if there is a specific trick or algorithm inside what is unique then it is worth sharing.

having clear why it is important to share you may create a question to how to do it. then you may answer your own question. it is not forbidden.

Comment: I do think that some basic graphics are really important to lower the gap for beginners of LaTeX. If you are very experienced in LaTeX it all looks very simple. If you are a beginner and you see complex figures with a nice trick (I don't like to use the trick, because that gives me a one lucky shot that is not universal ;-), that it is quicky discouraging to start. And I really believe that with some simple basic codes, you can persuade new LaTeX users to start making simple drawings. :-)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you having an account on GitHub would be very good. GitHub is a platform hosting code for version control and collaboration.