# Contributing to texexample --- error?

Tags: support

I was trying to submit a graphic to texexample ( as suggested in [How can I contribute to others with examples](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5934/how-can-i-contribute-to-others-with-examples) ), but I repeatedly receive this from the contact page:

[image: Error from texexample contact page]

Am I doing something wrong?

PS I understand this is not *strictly* relatex to tex.sx but I tend to consider texexample.net a near relative...

Comment: It's perhaps not strictly related to TeX.SX, but I doubt that it is a question for Meta.TeX.SX...

Comment: While this is off-topic (in my point of view), I don't think that it's necessary to downvote this question ;-) (Again, my point of view!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I maintain this site, and there's an error in the protection against [Cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) (CSRF) aka session riding, a kind of possible attacks. I still had not enough time to investigate and to fix it. I will do.

However, you don't need to use the web formular. On the same page there's my email address, you can send your graphic via email to me.

I did not add examples since a quite long time, but I still have contributions in my mailbox, and I bookmarked some great TeX.SX examples for adding to the gallery. And some new of my own. So hopefully very soon we can see updates.